# Copy only addition changes in split mode github/git

Tags: git, github

Further to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092191/how-to-merge-latest-changes-from-a-base-repo-to-a-forked-repo), I have merged the changes. But still there are some customisations in an another commit. From that commit I have to get some of the changes from some specific files(not all changes of a file).

Since I went to github commit in split mode & tried to copy the content. but it seems it copies  both additions and deletions for that file eg.[image: these changes].

- Is there any tool that will allow me to copy only additions part from selected lines?
- Any command line tool also be ok.

Comment: I think you want the file contents of some files at that commit, if thats what you want you can just checkout the commit using `git checkout <hash-of-commit>` and copy the file contents.. If you need something else please elaborate....

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve/what your goal is, so I'm not sure this helps you, but from your git bash/command line you could filter the output of `git diff` on anything that starts with a `+` to get all the additions. E.g. `git diff changed.file|egrep '^\+ '`.

Comment: @Oldskool - Thank you! That's nice! helpful may be next time now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git add -p

can be used to commit some changes(not all) with in a file.